# Using one Qpid broker and multiple queues

Tags: python, qpid

I'll explain my situation bit first. What want to accomplish, is multiple producers and multiple consumers and one broker on my server. I want messages to be persistent and queues to be durable. I want to have multiple queues that do not interfere with each other. With one queue and one producer and one consumer this works already fine.
Current code:

Consumer:

```
from qpid.connection import Connection
from qpid.datatypes import Message, uuid4
from qpid.util import connect

socket = connect('localhost',5672)
connection = Connection(sock=socket, username='***', password='***')
connection.start()
session = connection.session(str(uuid4()))
local_queue_name = 'my_queue'
queue = session.incoming(local_queue_name)
session.message_subscribe(queue='ProdSixQueue', destination=local_queue_name)
queue.start()
content=''
while content != 'Done':
    message = queue.get(timeout=1000000)
    while(queue.empty() == True):
        time.sleep(1)
    content = message.body
    if(validate(etree.fromstring(content))):
        session.message_accept(RangedSet(message.id)) 
        store(content) #my function to store data..
```

Producer:

```
from qpid.connection import Connection
from qpid.datatypes import Message, uuid4
from qpid.util import connect

def produce(theMsg):
        socket = connect('ser.ver.s.ip',5672)
        connection = Connection(sock=socket,username='***',password='***')
        connection.start()
        session = connection.sesssion(str(uuid4()))
        session.queue_declare(queue='ProdSixQueue')
        session.exchange_bind(exchange='amg.direct',queue='ProdSixQueue',binding_key='routing_key')
        properties = session.delivery_properties(routing_key='routing_key')
        session.message_transfer(destination='amq.direct',message=Message(properties,str(theMsg)))
        session.close(timeout=100)
```

Of course, those are not the whole program, but they are all the code that is involved in Qpid broker.

**The problem** now is if I make new consumer and producer to different devices, and have different traffic that I would like to move from producer to consumer, the first consumer steals all the data from broker even though I send it to different queue, like ProdSevenQueue, and at other consumer try to store it different local queue like "prodseven_local_Queue". Do I have to use the queues differently somehow or do I misunderstand the whole idea here? Also I hear people talking about configuring broker top redirect certain kind of traffic to somewhere else, yet I find no examples of this. Push to right direction would be awesome. To confuse you even more, here's picture of situation: [Link to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA8nO.png)

For my defense, I've never done anything with AMQP or Apache Qpid before, and I'm still learning python too. Also to complain bit more, I have never seen more incoherent documentation then Apache Qpid has. No love for new players obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program suggests a misunderstanding of the way Qpid works.

In Qpid (for AMQP protocols 0-8 to 0-10) message producers send messages to **Exchanges**. The Exchange is then responsible for routing the message to zero or more **Queues**. The precise details of that routing depend on the exchange type. It is through this mechanism that Qpid supports common messaging topologies (point-to-point, publish/subscribe, fanout etc).

Your use-case requires the use of an instance of a direct exchange (such as the built-in amq.direct).

A direct exchange routes messages to queues based on an exact match between the routing key of the message, and the binding key used to bind the queue to the exchange. A common convention is to bind the queue to the exchange using the name of queue itself as binding key.  It appears your program is currently using the string "routing_key" for this purpose, and I suspect will explain the undesired behaviour you observed.

You will find more explanation here:

http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.24/java-broker/book/Java-Broker-Concepts-Exchanges.html (Qpid Java Broker documentation - but the concept is shared)

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.1/html/Messaging_User_Guide/chap-Messaging_User_Guide-Exchanges.html (Redhat's MRG docs explain the same concepts with useful diagrams)

The Python Examples (see Qpid website) are a useful reference.